# get data from list of array by using c#

Tags: c#

i have problem with getting some data from list of array

the list is

date,id,bid,time,talk,st

```
2017-07-26 23:53:14,15a4ca7e,13,274,265,OK
2017-07-26 23:56:11,14f418a8,29,131,108,OK
2017-07-26 23:55:59,14df675e,31,189,168,OK
2017-07-26 23:56:54,1557ff5c,30,155,155,OK
2017-07-26 23:55:56,158db0b1,04,221,219,OK
2017-07-26 23:57:48,155a9e93,39,118,110,OK
2017-07-26 23:59:08,15aa6a2c,30,44,23,OK
2017-07-27 00:00:16,1596cd53,66,0,0,BUSY
2017-07-26 23:59:37,15aa68bc,30,61,51,OK
2017-07-27 00:00:10,150994b8,66,30,0,BUSY
2017-07-26 23:59:59,15aa6a2c,41,45,14,OK
2017-07-26 23:53:50,14df706d,02,420,419,OK
2017-07-26 23:57:32,14d5b722,22,205,192,OK
2017-07-26 23:58:00,150ff690,35,194,187,OK
2017-07-27 00:00:57,15aa6a2c,44,51,38,OK
2017-07-27 00:01:04,15a4afb7,30,49,48,OK
2017-07-27 00:00:32,15a1c53f,04,85,77,OK
2017-07-27 00:00:46,159fb87c,31,102,94,OK
2017-07-27 00:02:27,15590a6b,02,19,18,OK
2017-07-26 23:59:26,14fa65b7,16,201,178,OK
2017-07-27 00:02:42,15aa6a55,35,52,51,OK
```

this my code

```
    private List<ColList> colListItems = new List<ColList>();
    public List<ColList> readData(string filePath)
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);

        foreach (string readLine in sr.ReadToEnd().Split('\n'))
        {
            if (readLine != "")
            {
                string[] line = readLine.Split(',');
                colListItems.Add(new ColList()
                {
                    date = line[0],
                    id = line[1],
                    bid = int.Parse(line[2]),
                    time = int.Parse(line[3]),
                    talk = int.Parse(line[4]),
                    st = line[5]

                });
            }
        }

        return colListItems;
    }


public class ColList
{
    public string date;
    public string id;
    public int bid;
    public int time;
    public int talk;
    public string st;
}
```

i want to view the (id) that has max (time) from table above but must sum the (time) before get the max time the (id) is unique

this (id) is repeated (15aa6a2c) so i will sum the (time) and group his row in 1 row and if there is any duplicated row i will sum the (time) & (talk) column like this

```
2017-07-26 23:59:08    15aa6a2c    30    44    23    OK
2017-07-26 23:59:59    15aa6a2c    41    45    14    OK
2017-07-27 00:00:57    15aa6a2c    44    51    38    OK
```

it will be

```
2017-07-27 00:00:57    15aa6a2c    0    140    75    OK
```

and need to know how many times that the (id) repeatedly
    for (id) it's repeated 3 times

and what is the largest and lowest for (bid) depend on (st==OK) && (st!=OK) by counting them

for this require it's like this (30) has 4 row depend on st==OK and (22) has 1 row

```
2017-07-27 00:01:04    15a4afb7    30    49    48    OK
2017-07-26 23:59:08    15aa6a2c    30    44    23    OK
2017-07-26 23:56:54    1557ff5c    30    155    155    OK
2017-07-26 23:59:37    15aa68bc    30    61    51    OK

2017-07-26 23:58:00    150ff690    35    194    187    OK
2017-07-27 00:02:42    15aa6a55    35    52    51    OK


2017-07-26 23:59:59    15aa6a2c    41    45    14    OK
2017-07-27 00:00:57    15aa6a2c    44    51    38    OK


2017-07-26 23:53:50    14df706d    02    420    419    OK
2017-07-27 00:02:27    15590a6b    02    19    18    OK


2017-07-26 23:55:56    158db0b1    04    221    219    OK
2017-07-27 00:00:32    15a1c53f    04    85    77    OK

2017-07-27 00:00:46    159fb87c    31    102    94    OK
2017-07-26 23:55:59    14df675e    31    189    168    OK

2017-07-26 23:57:32    14d5b722    22    205    192    OK
```

Comment: "so i want to get the id who has many time by sum the time and get the max and to get the id that has many log repeatedly and max & min log for bid."
This is impossible to understand. Could you please rewrite?

Comment: @Sach i update the requirement

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still unintelligible to me. Maybe you could use your own data and show an example or your output data.

Comment: Do you want to find the item that has the largest 'time' value, and also the sum of all the 'time' properties in the list?

Also, if 'id' is unique, by definition it couldn't repeat.

Comment: i want to sum and find the largest time the id is unique after i make the summation before that it's not

Comment: That is still not understandable. What are you counting when you find the largest and lowest for `bid` per `st`? And the largest and lowest of what? Just out in the sample output you want.

Comment: You want to use `GroupBy` on the `Id` field, and then get the `Sum(Time)` and `Sum(Talk)`. Do you only want this for ids that have a status of `OK`?

Comment: using GroupBy without lose time & talk i want to remove duplicate but i want to sum(Time) & sum(Talk) and no need to OK it's just condition if st == OK then the counter +1

Comment: @NetMage how many row with same bid got duplicated when st == OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it looks like you want to use the `GroupBy` method to group your items by `Id`, and then find the one that meets some criteria.

Here is an example that should meet the requirement to find the Id that has the Maximum value of Talk after taking the Sum of Talk for all items with the same Id:

```
/// <summary>
/// Will return an item with the Id and Time for the items
/// in the list that have the max Sum(Time) for that id
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">A list of items to search</param>
/// <returns>A new item representing the Id with the Max(Sum(Time))</returns>
public static ColList GetIdWithMaxTime(List<ColList> input)
{
    // Argument validation
    if (input == null || !input.Any())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The input list must contain at least one item");
    }

    // Group items by Id, and select new items with the 
    // 'Time' field set to the sum of those for that Id
    var inputGroupedById = input
        .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
        .Select(i => new ColList
        {
            Date = i.Max(item => item.Date),
            Id = i.Key,
            Time = i.Sum(item => item.Time),
            Talk = i.Sum(item => item.Talk),
            St = i.First().St
        })
        .ToList();

    // Return the first one whose Time equals the Max(Time)
    return inputGroupedById.First(i => i.Time == inputGroupedById.Max(g => g.Time));
}
```

---

Here's another approach that might also help. I created a method that returns the whole list, grouped by Id, with the sum of Talk and the sum of Time:

```
/// <summary>
/// Will a list of all items grouped by the Id, 
/// with a Sum of the Time and Talk fields
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">A list of items to search</param>
/// <returns>A new item representing the Id with the Max(Sum(Time))</returns>
public static List<ColList> GroupItemsOnId(List<ColList> input)
{
    // Argument validation
    if (input == null || !input.Any())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The input list must contain at least one item");
    }

    // Group items by Id and select the sum for Time and Talk
    return input
        .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
        .Select(i => new ColList
        {
            Date = i.Max(item => item.Date),
            Id = i.Key,
            Time = i.Sum(item => item.Time),
            Talk = i.Sum(item => item.Talk),
            Status = i.First().Status
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

I also changed your class slightly, adding a `ToString()` override so we can output the items in a consistent manner:

```
public class ColList
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public int Talk { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Date}\t{Id}\t{BId}\t{Time}\t{Talk}\t{Status}";
    }
}
```

I'm also using this method to parse the text file, which is similar to yours but with some added error handling:

```
public static List<ColList> GetData(string filePath)
{
    var data = new List<ColList>();
    if (filePath == null || !File.Exists(filePath)) return data;
    var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line));

    foreach (var fileLine in fileLines)
    {
        var lineParts = fileLine.Split(',');
        int tmp;
        data.Add(new ColList()
        {
            Date = lineParts[0],
            Id = lineParts.Length > 0 ? lineParts[1] : "",
            BId = lineParts.Length > 1 && int.TryParse(lineParts[2], out tmp) ? tmp : 0,
            Time = lineParts.Length > 2 && int.TryParse(lineParts[3], out tmp) ? tmp : 0,
            Talk = lineParts.Length > 3 && int.TryParse(lineParts[4], out tmp) ? tmp : 0,
            Status = lineParts.Length > 4 ? lineParts[5] : ""
        });
    }

    return data;
}
```

Now we can use this new method to get a list of all the items, grouped by Id:

```
// Populate our colListItems list and get grouped items
var filePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.txt";
var items = GetData(filePath);
var groupedItems = GroupItemsOnId(items);
```

And now we can display our data by ordering the grouped items by Time or by Talk:

```
Console.WriteLine("Here are the items sorted by Time, followed by the times the Id repeated:");
foreach (var item in groupedItems.OrderByDescending(i => i.Time))
{
    // Get the count of this id, and if it was repeated more than once color the text green
    var countOfThisId = items.Count(i => i.Id == item.Id);
    var consoleColor = countOfThisId > 1 ? ConsoleColor.Green : Console.ForegroundColor;
    Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor;

    Console.WriteLine($"{item}\tId was repeated {countOfThisId} times.");

    Console.ResetColor();
}

Console.WriteLine("\nHere are the items sorted by Talk:");
foreach (var item in groupedItems.OrderByDescending(i => i.Talk))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This gives the output:

[image]

We don't need the grouped items to get the BId results. Instead we can filter our original list on `Status == "OK"` and then use `OrderByDescending` on the `BId` field to order the results:

```
// Order our results on 'BId' field           
Console.WriteLine("\nHere are the results ordered by BId where status is 'OK':");
int lastBid = 0;

foreach (var item in items.Where(i => 
    i.Status.Equals("OK")).OrderByDescending(i => i.BId))
{
    // Put a blank line between groups of BIds
    if (item.BId != lastBid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        lastBid = item.BId;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This produces the output:

[image]